# Как отсеять плохие особые точки в сравнении двух изображений глаз

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

[image: Сравнение двух изображений двух разных глаз]
[image: Сравнение двух изображений одного глаза]

Мне нужно с помощью ORB проводить идентификацию по радужной оболочке глаза, но я не понимаю, как с помощью точек, которые я получил, сделать вывод совпадают ли изображения глаз или нет?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ORB = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1500, nlevels=8)
BF = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING2, crossCheck=True)

def orb(img):
    kp, ds = ORB.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    return kp, ds

def match(kp1, ds1, im1, kp2, ds2, im2):
    matches = sorted(BF.match(ds1, ds2), key=lambda x: x.distance)[0:30]
    m1_xy = []
    m2_xy = []
    cv2.imshow(f"{np.random.random()}", cv2.drawMatches(im1, kp1, im2, kp2, matches, None, flags=2))
    for m in matches:
        (x1, y1) = kp1[m.queryIdx].pt
        (x2, y2) = kp2[m.trainIdx].pt
        m1_xy.append([x1, y1])
        m2_xy.append([x2, y2])


    return 0
```